# Django Left Join With Filter on Custom Many to Many Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have 3 models (User-default model , Project, ClickedUsers-custom m2m model) and I want to perform left join with filter in ORM on ClickedUsers and Project models. I tried the solutions on Stack Overflow but when I print those queries I saw they performed Inner join.

Here are my models :

```
class Project(models.Model):
        …
    clicked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User,through='ClickedUsers',blank=True)


class ClickedUsers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And the query I want to perform :

```
select * from project LEFT JOIN clickedusers ON project.id = clickedusers.project_id WHERE clickedusers.user_id = 1;
```

How can I done this query with django orm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` won't give you different results from an `INNER JOIN` in this query

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 on table_2.table_1_id = table_1.id
WHERE table_2.field = some_value;
```

Since you have a field from table_2 in the where clause, you can only get results from table_1 when there is a record in table_2. A `LEFT JOIN` says to get records from table_1 even if there is no record in table_2 satisfying the join criteria.

The reason you aren't getting the query from the ORM that you want is that the ORM recognizes it can use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` without changing the results.

Comment: I didn't know there is a intelligent mechanism in django that can understand this. Because of this I confused. Thanks , your answer enlightened me.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the reverse relationships and [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

```
Project.objects.filter(clicked_users__id=1)
```

Or you use the through model:

```
Project.objects.filter(clickedusers_set__user_id=1)
```

Edit:
I missed the * from `select * from`. If you need all the fields, then you'll need to use:

```
ClickedUser.objects.filter(
    user_id=1,
).select_related('project')
```

Comment: I tried those queryies and just before, I tried again. Both performed Inner join. Here is the printed query : 
SELECT "paftapp_project"."id", "paftapp_project"."deadline", "paftapp_project"."has_model", "paftapp_project"."has_render", "paftapp_project"."description", "paftapp_project"."documentation_path", "paftapp_project"."is_called", "paftapp_project"."map_sheet_id", "paftapp_project"."customer_id" FROM "paftapp_project" INNER JOIN "paftapp_clickedusers" ON ("paftapp_project"."id" = "paftapp_clickedusers"."project_id") WHERE "paftapp_clickedusers"."user_id" = 1

Comment: As you may notice, all fields that getted by query are belong to Project model. I want to get Project model fields along with ClickedUser model fields.

Comment: I added the queryset that will generate what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it returned all fields of two models but unfortunately, it is still inner join.

Comment: SELECT "paftapp_clickedusers"."id", "paftapp_clickedusers"."user_id", "paftapp_clickedusers"."project_id", "paftapp_clickedusers"."status", "paftapp_project"."id", "paftapp_project"."deadline", "paftapp_project"."has_model", "paftapp_project"."has_render", "paftapp_project"."description", "paftapp_project"."documentation_path", "paftapp_project"."is_called", "paftapp_project"."map_sheet_id", "paftapp_project"."customer_id" FROM "paftapp_clickedusers" INNER JOIN "paftapp_project" ON ("paftapp_clickedusers"."project_id" = "paftapp_project"."id") WHERE "paftapp_clickedusers"."user_id" = 1

Comment: A left join on project from clickedusers gains you nothing. ClickedUser.project is not allowed to be nullable so you'll never have a row in clickedusers that doesn't have a matching row in project.